# How to store chat messages in blockchain?

Tags: chat, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

I am writing a chat application using `Angular`, `Node.Js`, `WebRTC` and `Socket.io`. I am using `Cassandra` database to store data. I want to use blockchain in chat application. Is there any mechanism to store chat messages in blockchain? Currently I am storing hash of sent messages in blockchain after user closes chat application. Can anyone please suggest any other way to store chat messages in blockchain?

Comment: Just an opinion - blockchains tend to be slow databases. Most cloud providers offer immutable /WORM storage which offer cheaper and more performant mechanisms for permanent, tamper proof storage

Comment: keep in mind that every data you store in blockchain is accompanied by a transaction and that transaction has a cost.

Comment: Which blockchain you are using? You have a tag for both Ethereum and Hyperledger-fabric. The solution for the two would be very different

Answer (score 1):

I would just avoid using Cassandra.
You can directly store data inside the blockchain, in your case, chat messages.

Download the [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) and you will see that in the fabcar application some car data are stored.
I suggest to learn from that example to make your application.

You could store messages with a Key-Pair (Sender - Message) or with JSON, the way you prefer.
They will be immutable in the ledger, but remember that storing data inside the blockchain is a little bit slower than a normal database.